# Regression algorithm for weak correlated target and features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, modeling, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a regression problem in hand. Dataset have 20 predictors and 1 target. Target is continuous and predictors are both categorical and continous. I performed a correlation test between continous predictors and target and found very week to negligible linear relation.

```
#selecting numeric / continous variables
numCols <- unlist(lapply(employee_data_Imputed,is.numeric))
numVarDataset <- employee_data_Imputed[,numCols]
# Visualizing correlation 
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
corr <- cor(numVarDataset)
corrplot(
  corr,
  method = "color",
  outline = TRUE,
  cl.pos = 'n',
  rect.col = "black",
  tl.col = "indianred4",
  addCoef.col = "black",
  number.digits = 2,
  number.cex = 0.60,
  tl.cex = 0.70,
  cl.cex = 1,
  col = colorRampPalette(c("green4", "white", "red"))(100)
)

# 1. We found no strong relationship between target and predictors.
# 2. No strong correlation was found among predictors in dataset.
```

[image]

Here Absenteeism.in.hours is my target. My question is how should i approach this kind of data. What can be an appropriate machine learning technique for regression in this case.

Structure of my dataset is

```
> str(employee_data_Imputed)
'data.frame':   740 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ ID                             : Factor w/ 36 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 11 36 3 7 11 3 10 20 14 1 ...
 $ Reason.for.absence             : Factor w/ 28 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 26 20 23 7 23 23 22 23 19 22 ...
 $ Month.of.absence               : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Day.of.the.week                : Factor w/ 5 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 5 1 1 ...
 $ Seasons                        : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Transportation.expense         : num  289 118 179 279 289 179 361 260 155 235 ...
 $ Distance.from.Residence.to.Work: num  36 13 51 5 36 51 52 50 12 11 ...
 $ Service.time                   : num  13 18 18 14 13 18 3 11 14 14 ...
 $ Age                            : num  33 50 38 39 33 38 28 36 34 37 ...
 $ Work.load.Average.day          : num  239554 239554 239554 239554 239554 ...
 $ Hit.target                     : num  97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 ...
 $ Disciplinary.failure           : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Education                      : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 ...
 $ Son                            : num  2 1 0 2 2 0 1 4 2 1 ...
 $ Social.drinker                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Social.smoker                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Pet                            : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 4 0 0 1 ...
 $ Weight                         : num  90 98 89 68 90 89 80 65 95 88 ...
 $ Height                         : num  172 178 170 168 172 170 172 168 196 172 ...
 $ Body.mass.index                : num  30 31 31 24 30 31 27 23 25 29 ...
 $ Absenteeism.time.in.hours      : num  4 0 2 4 2 2 8 4 8 8 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have found that each individual continuous independent variable (IV) has at most a weak correlation with the dependent variable (DV). This does NOT mean that many IVs in combination will not explain much of the variance in the DV. Especially since the IVs are weakly correlated with each other, meaning that they may be contributing independent explanatory power.

Two other important factors that may help you:

1) Interactions between IVs may be important in explaining variance in the DV.

2) Your correlations ignore all the information contained in the categorical variables - which might be substantial.

Depending on your goals, a standard regression approach should be fine in this case; regularisation would probably be a good idea given your limited data. If you want to use a ML technique, random forests might work fine too, though again data limitation might be an issue.